# Reveal module pattern: Where to insert variables for module access

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm learning reveal module pattern, and I'm trying to create a reusable function. (In my project, the function will make the page scroll. I don't think it's necessary to post the whole code here. I'm just putting the concept.)

The basic overview is, there's a function that will not return anything. There's no need for public variables. Here's the code. The questions are at the comments in the code:

#### JSFiddle

```js
var MyModule = (function() {
  // Is this the correct place to insert the
  // variables that will be used throughout 'MyModule'?
  var foo = 'foo',
    foo2 = 'foo2',
    param1 = null;

  var MyModule = function(_param1) {
    param1 = _param1;

    logParam();
  };

  function init() {
    foo = 'something';
  }

  function logParam() {
    console.log(param1);
  }

  init();

  return MyModule;
})();

var module = new MyModule('Some Paramater');

// Is this okay? Does it still follow reveal module pattern?
MyModule('Some Other Paramater');
// Or do I always have to do like this:
var module = new MyModule('Some Paramater');
```

Comment: The JS world has moved on. It's an ES6 world, and if you haven't already you should get on the train. ES6 has built-in module capabilities, so all the "revealing module" and related patterns everyone has been learning for the last decade are no longer relevant. Variables declared with `var` etc. in a file are by definition private to that module. Instead of returning objects with interfaces, we just export those interfaces, and then import them when needed. I suggest you direct your efforts toward learning about modules of the future, not of the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Module Reveal Pattern provides both private and public encapsulation.

Below an example with some explanatory comments.

More info about JavaScript pattern included Module Reveal Pattern can be found [here](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)

```js
var myRevealingModule = (function () {
        // below are private variables and functions that are not accessible outside the module this is possible thanks to a javascript closure
        var privateVar = "Ben Cherry",
            publicVar = "Hey there!";
 
        function privateFunction() {
            console.log( "Name:" + privateVar );
        }
        // below are public functions, they will be publicly available as they are referenced in the return statement below
        function publicSetName( strName ) {
            privateVar = strName;
        }
 
        function publicGetName() {
            privateFunction();
        }
 
 
        // Reveal public pointers to
        // private functions and properties
 
        return {
            setName: publicSetName,
            greeting: publicVar,
            getName: publicGetName
        };
 
    })();
 
myRevealingModule.setName( "Paul Kinlan" );
console.log(myRevealingModule.greeting);// public
console.log(myRevealingModule.getName());// public
//console.log(myRevealingModule.privateFunction());// private, you cannot access it
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How would I create a constructor?

Comment: @Horay please use the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/ddg1p465/ were basically you add your function constructor as a member of the module. Please let me know if I can provide you more infos. If you think my answer helped you out, please do not forget to accept it or up voting using tick icon on its left side. Thanks and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your comments:

```
// Is this okay? Does it still follow reveal module pattern?
MyModule('Some Other Paramater');
```

Yes, it's OK. If you want that your reveal module pattern "**MyModule**" must be selfclosing:

```
var MyModule = function(param1) {
    var myPlublicFunction = function(){
    }

    return {
      myPlublicFunction: myPlublicFunction
    };
}(); //selfclosing
```

OR

```
// Or do I always have to do like this:
var module = new MyModule('Some Paramater');
```

If you want that, your reveal module pattern "**MyModule**" must be not selfclosing:

```
var MyModule = function(param1) {
    var myPlublicFunction = function(){
    }

    return {
      myPlublicFunction: myPlublicFunction
    };
}; // not selfclosing
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Just tried your second example (the one with `new`) and it crashes with the following log: 'MyModule is not a constructor`. https://jsfiddle.net/31deytue/

Comment: Ok, changed, check it out [https://jsfiddle.net/31deytue/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/31deytue/5/)